# Is data explorer down?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer

When I go to [data.stackexchange.com](//data.stackexchange.com), I get a message stay that it is down for maintenance.  It has been down for over 1 hr.  There is no mention of this outage on twitter.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is down. There is nothing on the Stack_Status twitter feed so [I pinged the status bot](https://twitter.com/patrick_hofman/status/785843894202269696), so hopefully it will end up at the right person.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, we dropped the ball on this one.

The data explorer is back online now.

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: Don't know just yet. I've recycled the application pool which got it back online, but am still digging into what caused it to go offline in the first place. Looks like some form of connection exhaustion.